# Slow background task and frequent crashing (App using NewsAPI)

Tags: java, android, performance

I am working on a News app using newsapi. I have a homepage that downloads the top 15 articles and another page that has does the same but from the hackernews api. Each time I run the app from Android Studio, it shows a white screen for a few minutes before populating the list view.

I tried limiting the download rate, kept a check on the SQLite indexes and other things from StackOverflow but I can't seem to solve my issue.

- When I go to the hackernews page and click on list, the app will just refresh itself and come back to the homepage
- When running app from the emulator, it will either go to hackernews without loading homepage or just crash
- java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 when clicking last item in listview
- App will only load 2 articles and give me a java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.summarizebot.com/api/summariz... error. This is because the URL from the API doesn't work (tested in the browser)

Homepage

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ...
//START THE BACKGROUND TASK
    task = new BackgroundTask();    
        String s = task.execute("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey").get();
    ...
//POPULATE LIST WITH DATABASE CONTENT
    updateContent();


public void updateContent(){        
    ...
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        homeStories.clear();
        homeLinks.clear();
    }

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        do {
            homeStories.add(cursor.getString(nameIndex));
            homeLinks.add(cursor.getString(addressIndex));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//BACKGROUND TASK
public class  BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground (String...urls){
//GET JSON AND SUMMARIES IN SINGLE FOR LOOP FOR EACH ARTICLE
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            JSONObject content = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        ...
//ADD TO DATABASE
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO trending (name, address) VALUES ('" + title + "','" + address + "')");

 //GET THE SUMMARY OF EACH ARTICLE             
             url = new URL("https://www.summarizebot.com/api/summarize?...         
             JSONArray j2Array = new JSONArray(s1);
                 for (int j = 0; j < j2Array.length(); j++) {
                     JSONObject object2 = j2Array.getJSONObject(j);
                        s2 += object2.getString("sentence");
                    }

  //END OF MAIN FOR LOOP
         }
```

Hackernews Page

```
 //SAME AS ABOVE
```

After attempting to troubleshoot, I came up with a few questions:

- How can I speed up background tasks for news articles?
- How can I open an app and start background downloads without it crashing because of indexOutOfBounds?
- How can I give download priority to the current activity instead of downloading everything at once?
- How do I skip over broken links and continue getting the rest of the articles? App stops downloading at that point [**FIXED: Surrounded InputStream with Try/Catch**]

Comment: `frequent crashing`  Where is your crash log you need to share it with the question Have a look **[Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)**

Comment: paste your crash log please

Comment: The logs are really weird. Sometimes it doesn't appear at all. I can pm the GitHub link if it helps.

Comment: in your doinbackground first for loop index value must be less than ur array size , you write 16 instead of array size , it should be like this 
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { ...}
because of this you are getting indexoutofboundexception .. array size is 1 and your loop index  run until 16 size. change it and then check

Comment: I tried it and it didn't seem to help much. Thanks though. I get an index out of bounds because the data hasn't downloaded yet and I'm requesting it.